# Collect information about current server in cross platform way

Tags: java, hostname

We have some java apps, may be invoked from the command line or inside a web server. Either way they log to a central database. It would be very useful to be able to setup our java apps to read the hostname (or some other unique identifier) on startup, so they can report which server they are running on for debugging purposes. Is there such a mechanism in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [`ManagementFactory#getRuntimeMXBean()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getRuntimeMXBean%28%29) fairly effectively for debugging purposes. You probably just want the [name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getName%28%29):

```
String localHostName = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
```

> Returns the name representing the running Java virtual machine. The returned name string can be any arbitrary string and a Java virtual machine implementation can choose to embed platform-specific useful information in the returned name string. Each running virtual machine could have a different name.

Comment: @Jacob just another drive-by downvote for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2):

Just try

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```